# What is the approach for adding a persistent section at the top of a list?

Tags: android, listview

I'm really not sure how to approach this problem.  I want to have 3 - 4 'list items' at the top of my list that never change, but scroll with the list. The rest of the list is populated using a ListAdapter and works perfectly.

What way do people do this?  I've considered using a ScrollView instead of a List, but the code seems longer and more difficult than it should be.  As far as I'm aware you can't have a ListView inside a ScrollView either. Do I need to change my adapter so that if I'm calling 'getView' with positions < 4 then I pass one of my views that are unrelated to the rest of the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use [addHeaderView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29) method from ListView. You can add many different headers and headers always scroll with list. So just try to add four headers.